# Where are view_counts stored?

Tags: count

I have one entry that has way more views than any other. I cant find it set as a deafult entry anywhere so I dont know how it got so high. I want to manually set it back to a lower number, then see how much it increases in one day.

Where is that view_count_entry amount for an an entry stored?  A db search for teh view count comes up empty...

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View counts are stored in the `exp_channel_titles` table - `view_count_one`, `view_count_two`, etc.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/entry_tracking.html

Answer (score 2):

The hits for templates are stored in the exp_templates table. The column is called "hits".

Generally speaking though I think that you might get a more accurte idea on where the hits are coming from if you use Google Analytics.